# Ruby on Rails multiple many to many relations between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I have two relations m:n type that links a table `Users` with a table `Videos`. I create it by these line command:

```
rails generate migration users_comments_videos
rails generate migration users_views_videos
```

In the files user.rb and videos.rb I respectively added the instructions:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
```

Are these two instructions valid for for both of the relations that I created?

Comment: Please `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead `had_and_belongs_to_many` and yes, both are valid.

Comment: Ciao Giacomo, sei nuovo con Rails? fa comodo sapere che c'è una persona in più nella comunità Rails italiana ;-) Anyway, what's the problem? Did you just want to know if you wrote the right code?

Comment: Ciao, si con Rails sono nuovo, ma più lo sto studiando più mi sta piacendo...for the question in english...yes i want to know right this...

Answer (score 2):

Pick different association names and then specify the model.

user.rb

```
class User
  has_many :comments
  has_many :views
  has_many :comment_videos, :through => :comments, :source => 'Video'
  has_many :view_videos, :through => :views, :source => 'Video'
end
```

video.rb

```
class Video
  has_many :comments
  has_many :views
  has_many :comment_users, :through => :comments, :source => 'User'
  has_many :view_users, :through => :views, :source => 'User'
end
```

Comment: comments and views are not tables or entities but relationship. In the mapping of e/r model the relations m:n type comments and the relation views becomes table. For example the migrate file for comments is this class UsersCommentsVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users_comments_videos, :id => false do |t|
     t.column :user_id, :integer
     t.column :video_id, :integer
     t.column :text, :string
     t.column :datecreationtext, :datetime
     
     t.timestamps
    end ....

Comment: I have edited the answer showing how to have multiple many-to-many relationships between two models.

Comment: @Anil: How do you generate the migrations for these joins. Moreover, how do you insert the values to them. Thanks